# GAE + Flask Contact Form

Tags: python, email, flask, google-app-engine, contact-form

I'm trying to build a simple contact form with Flask and hosting it on GAE but I can't seem to get it right.

I'd truly appreciate your help because I've spent several days trying to figure this out without any success.

Here's the error I get when I click submit:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

And here are the logs:

```
2022-02-14 23:03:33 default[20220215t000150]  Traceback (most recent call last):    
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app      response = self.full_dispatch_request()    
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request      rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)    
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request      rv = self.dispatch_request()    
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request      return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)    
File "/srv/main.py", line 34, in contact      message.send()    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/appengine/api/mail.py", line 1209, in send      make_sync_call('mail', self._API_CALL, message, response)    
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 96, in MakeSyncCall      return stubmap.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)    
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 355, in MakeSyncCall      rpc.CheckSuccess()    
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_rpc.py", line 149, in CheckSuccess      raise self.exception    
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/appengine/runtime/default_api_stub.py", line 267, in _CaptureTrace      f(**kwargs)    
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/appengine/runtime/default_api_stub.py", line 260, in _SendRequest      raise self._TranslateToError(parsed_response)    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/appengine/runtime/default_api_stub.py", line 134, in _TranslateToError      raise self._ErrorException(exception_type, msg)  google.appengine.runtime.apiproxy_errors.FeatureNotEnabledError: The API call mail.Send() is currently not enabled. -- Additional details from server: App Engine APIs are not enabled, please add app_engine_apis: true to your app.yaml to enable.
```

Here's my main.py:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, url_for
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
from flask_talisman import Talisman
from google.appengine.api import mail, wrap_wsgi_app

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'my-very-very-secret-key'
app.wsgi_app = wrap_wsgi_app(app.wsgi_app)
Talisman(app)

EMAIL_ADDR = 'my_email@example.com'

class ContactForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField(label='Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField(label='Submit')

@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/contact', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def contact():
    form = ContactForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name = form.name.data

        message = mail.EmailMessage(sender=EMAIL_ADDR,
                                    subject='form test')
        message.body = f'this is a test message from {name}'
        message.to = EMAIL_ADDR
        message.send()

        return redirect(url_for('homepage'))

    return render_template('contact.html', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

My app.yaml

```
runtime: python39

app_engine_apis: true

inbound_services:
- mail
- mail_bounce
```

My requirements.txt

```
Flask==2.0.2
flask-talisman==0.8.1
wtforms==3.0.0
Flask-WTF==1.0.0
appengine-python-standard>=0.3.1
```

Comment: You have to tell us the problem you're having. For example, if you're getting an http error, include it. Also include a copy of the log. Is this working on Dev and then failing on Production? Or is this not working at all on Dev?

Comment: The error I get when I click submit is:

'''Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.'''

'''

Here's the last part of the logs, it's too long for the amount of characters in these replies.

Additional details from server: App Engine APIs are not enabled, please add app_engine_apis: true to your app.yaml to enable.

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled upon the solution! If anyone else runs into this issue: 'gcloud beta app deploy' solves it. I used to deploy the app with 'gcloud app deploy' before.

Comment: Yes. If you're using the bundled services in the newer runtimes, you have to use the beta version of gcloud app deploy